# Keeping params through a redirect_to RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hey I want to redirect_to and keep my params from the last page. The parameter is invite_token but I can't smiply get it to work.

I've tried several versions of this:

```
@invitation = Invitation.find_by_invite_token    
redirect_to sign_up_path(params[:invite_token])
or
redirect_to sign_up_path(params[:invite_token => @invitation.invite_token]
```

Comment: Please try with this `redirect_to sign_up_path(:invite_token => @invitation.invite_token)`

Answer (score 0):

```
redirect_to some_path(invite_token: @invitation.invite_token)
# or
redirect_to controller: :some_controller, action: :create, invite_token: @invitation.invite_token
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you need all params to persist just pass the `params`:

```
redirect_to sign_up_path(params)
```